# user Access Rights to Hadoop Scheduler

Tags: hadoop, scheduler

I have a scheduler on my claster `http://hadoop:8088/cluster/scheduler` where I can see all my queues, running applications and so on... 
When I click on selected appliction, go into details. 
In the left-top corner there is a link 'Kill application' which allows my to kill selected application. 
The problem is that you don't have to log in to the scheduler (always logged as Logged in as: dr.who) so you are allowed to kill any application!

Is there any chance to prevent this? One solution is to give the access to the scheduler only to selected group of people. But even they can do something wrong by accident. Is there any way to turn on logging? Or remove 'Kill application' link?

Regards
Pawel

Comment: You would 1) Need to Kerberize your cluster 2) Enable SPENGO authentication to the YARN UI

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/49429/how-to-disable-kill-application-button-in-yarn-web.html